# Android custom XferMode / PorterDuff.Mode

Tags: android, opengl-es, porter-duff

There are some predefined blending modes described here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html

Is there a possibility to use some other custom modes? (for drawing various stuff on Canvas)

For example, I really need two more:

- Replace the alpha (it would be written as `[Sa, Dc]` if I understand right)
- Blend using destination alpha `[Sa, Da * Sc + (1 - Da) * Dc]` (here I don't really care about the result's alpha)

And it would be OK if it would require OpenGL ES 2+.

There's a [remotely] similar question here: [Implementing different PorterDuff modes in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13237157/1418097) — but the answer seems to require using two bitmaps, and I want to stay free of temporary bitmaps, because they are… not free.

Comment: what about ColorMatrixColorFilter?

Comment: ColorFilter can't be used for blending _two_ images, it can only apply a transform to _one_ image, isn't it?

Comment: When saying "blending" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: draw image A (a `Paint` probably) over an existing image B (`Canvas`), using some function with 2 inputs (pixel from A, pixel from B) to compute the final pixels.

Comment: @pskink "blending" means "mixing". He wants to overlay 2 images.